# Matcher.Find() returns false when it should be true

Tags: java, regex

```
        String s = "test";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\n((\\w+\\s*[^\\n]){0,2})(\\b" + s + "\\b\\s)((\\w+\\s*){0,2})\\n?");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(searchableText);
        boolean topicTitleFound = matcher.find();
        startIndex = 0;
        while (topicTitleFound) {
            int i = searchableText.indexOf(matcher.group(0));
            if (i > startIndex) {
                builder.append(documentText.substring(startIndex, i - 1));
        ...
```

This is the text that I tacle:

> Some text comes here
>
> topicTitle test :
>   
> test1 : testing123
>   
> test2 : testing456 
>   
> test3 : testing789
>   
> test4 : testing9097

When I'm testing this regex on http://regexpal.com/ or http://www.regexplanet.com I clearly find the title that is saying: "topicTitle test". But in my java code topicTitleFound returns false.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you have carriage-return characters (`'\r'`) before the newline characters (`'\n'`) in your `searchableText`. This would cause the match to fail at line boundaries.

To make your multi-line pattern more robust, try using the [MULTILINE](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) option when compiling the regex. Then use `^` and `$` as needed to match line boundaries.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

---

**Update:**

After actually testing out your code, I see that the pattern matches whether carriage-returns are present or not. In other words, your code "works" as-is, and `topicTitleFound` is `true` when it is first assigned (outside the `while` loop).

Are you sure that you are getting `false` for `topicTitleFound`? Or is the problem in the loop?

By the way, the use of `indexOf()` is wasteful and awkward, since the matcher already stores the index at which group 0 begins. Use this instead:

```
int i = matcher.start(0);
```

Comment: thanks but this doesn't work. Funny thing is, on other places in the text with different words it works perfectly.

Comment: @Rob Hufschmitt - What is funny is that it works just fine for me. Are you sure that the code you posted is what you are actually testing? Reduce your code to the simplest case possible that still reproduces the bug and post it exactly. Define references like `searchableText` with literal strings. Complete the loop (if that's required to demonstrate the bug) so that it compiles. The code you posted works; if you are still having a problem, post the code that is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is a bit hard to decrypt - not really obvious what you're trying to do. One thing that springs to mind is that your regex expects the match to start with a newline, and your sample text doesn't.